# LotusScript getNextDocument quantity of documents

Tags: view, lotus-domino, lotusscript, agent

1. I've a NotesView named "status" with selection: documentStatus = 0,
2. I've an lotusscript agent which gets all document from "status" view and change the documentStatus value to 1.

After agent run the "status" view should be empty but there are documents which agent didn't process.

Were I made a mistake?

There is a Lotussript code:

```
Set doc = view.Getfirstdocument()
While Not ( doc Is Nothing)
    Set docNext = view.Getnextdocument(doc)
    Call doc.Replaceitemvalue("documentStatus", 1)
    Call doc.Save(True, True)
    Set doc = docNext
Wend
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your code with a line

```
view.AutoUpdate = false
```

This prevents your view being refreshed during agent run.

Answer (score 1):

It's far better to gather the documents into a collection, then step through the collection making your change

```
view.AutoUpdate = false
```

will stop the view from being refreshed while you work, so will stop the server receiving many updates for view re-indexing

If there are very very many, you might want to consider turning replication off until you've finished as well

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out.

I think that view.GetNextDocument(doc) didn't assign the document to docNext variable but the possition of the document in the view. After agent saved the document it was deleted from view (because of selection criterion) and loop get wrong document missing some.

Instead of view.GetNextDocument(doc) I used view.GetFirstDocument() in the end of loop.

I modify my code to:

```
Set doc = view.Getfirstdocument()
While Not ( doc Is Nothing)
    Set docNext = view.Getnextdocument(doc)
    Call doc.Replaceitemvalue("documentStatus", 1)
    Call doc.Save(True, True)
    Set doc = view.Getfirstdocument()
Wend
```

Comment: This works but you might update the same document several times because view might not being refreshed after every document save. Especially when server is very busy this will happen. Better go with `view.AutoUpdate = false`...